# How do I clear the 3 textField values on button "Save" click

Tags: swift4

The screenshot is shown here:

[image]

I entered the values in these 3 textField ,
Now on button "Save" click, I want to clear the text in those 3 textfield at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set empty text on save button click action.

```
nameField.text = ""
ageField.text = ""
salaryField.text = ""
```